# Problema em deixar form como top c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho 2 forms. O principal contem um botão que abre o segundo form dentro do principal.

```
private void btnCalculadora_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculadora = new frmCalculadora();
        Calculadora.TopLevel = false;
        Calculadora.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(this.Calculadora);
        Calculadora.Location = new Point(210, 40);
    }
```

Porém gostaria que quando fosse aberto o secundário, ele ficasse selecionado, para que o evento **KeyPress** do form secundário funcionasse, mas **Calculadora.TopLevel = false;** não permite.

> Obs: Deixando TopLevel = true / this.Controls.Add(this.Calculadora);
>   da erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o seu Form principal como `MdiContainer`, e defina o `MdiParent` do seu Form secundário, como seu Form principal.

Exemplo:

```
private void btnCalculadora_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calculadora = new frmCalculadora();
    Calculadora.MdiParent = this;
    Calculadora.Location = new Point(210, 40);
    Calculadora.Show();
}
```

A propriedade MdiContainer pode ser definida no Form Principal, pela interface do visual studio, na janela de propriedades do Form

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: deu certo ? por favor marque como resposta e avalie utilizando as setas no lado esquerdo da publicação.